# Having trouble using ajax to load data from a php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first post. I'm new to using AJAX but trying to learn. I have an application that displays a table to the user of their open trouble tickets (all working well). I have a link in the table that fires the function below, only nothing is happening.

```
function loadTicketDetails(ticketNumber) {
    var loadingBar = document.getElementById('loadingArea');
    var ticketDetails = document.getElementById('ticketDetails');
    if (ticketDetails.style.display != 'block') {
        ticketDetails.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (ticketDetails.style.display != 'inline') {
        loadingBar.style.display = 'inline';
    }
    loadingBar.style.display = 'inline';
    if (document.getEleme)
        $.ajax({
            url: "ticketdetails.inline.php?ticketNumber=" + ticketNumber,
            dataType: "text/html",
            success: function(data) {
                $(".ticketDetails").html(data);
            }
        });
    if (ticketDetails.style.display != 'none') {
        loadingBar.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm probably missing something obvious here but any help would be appreciated.

For reference, here is what ticketdetails.inline.php?ticketNumber=ticketNumber should return:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"><span id="ticketTitle"><?echo $ticketTitle; ?></span><Span style="float: right; display: inline; cursor: pointer;" onClick="closeTicketPanel();">Close</Span></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <p><strong>Ticket Number:</strong> Ticket Number</p>
      <p><strong>Ticket Status:</strong> Ticket Status</p>
      <p><strong>Ticket Description:</strong> </p>
      <p>ERMAGERD, MY COMPOOTER IS BURNING</p>
      <br /><br />
      <p><strong>Ticket Notes:</strong></p>
      <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th width="693" style="text-align: left;">
              <strong>Note Title: </strong>Important ticket note
              <strong>Date</strong>: 2017-04-25 15:52
              <strong>Author:</strong> Jimmy John</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Important ticket note</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th width="693" style="text-align: left;">
              <strong>Note Title: </strong>Task Notes
              <strong>Date</strong>: 2017-04-25 16:01
              <strong>Author:</strong> Jimmy John</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Task Notes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th width="693" style="text-align: left;">
              <strong>Note Title: </strong>Task Detail
              <strong>Date</strong>: 2017-04-25 16:02
              <strong>Author:</strong> Jimmy John</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Task Detail</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the php return what you want when you run it manually? Can you alert/log the page your ajax is calling? Could you please add an `error` statement to your ajax call to see if it is successful at all? Why is `$(".ticketDetails").html(data);` referring to a `class` and not an `id`?

Comment: You need to change `dataType: "text/html"` to `dataType:"html"`

Comment: I got it fixed, but not sure what exactly fixed it. First, I changed the class to an ID and the data type, but that didn't work. As soon as I added the error function, it did work (didn't throw the error function)... Weird.